# Database access failure in VB .NET (without any error message)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, database-connection

I am creating a VB .NET project with database where I look to configure the connection string via app.config 's reference.
The problem is my project is running fine - creating database connection successfully, closing connection successfully and even pretending that insertion is also successful - But ultimately nothing happens as the net result nothing gets entered into the database..I have used Module.vb to use global codes.Here are my codes.

app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbstrc" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

now module.vb

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration

Module MyModule
    Public conn As New SqlConnection
    Public da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public cmd As New SqlCommand

    Public Sub connect()
        conn = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbstrc").ConnectionString
        Try
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("connection success")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try



    End Sub
End Module
```

And finally the form.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str As String
        str = "INSERT INTO tsttbl(Id,Name) VALUES('" & tb1.Text.Trim & "','" & tb2.Text.Trim & "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(str, conn)

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
            MsgBox("successfully entered")
            clrentry()
        Else
            MsgBox("errorrr!!")
        End If
        conn.Close()

    End Sub

    Public Sub clrentry()
        tb1.Text = ""
        tb2.Text = ""
        'connect()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**IN SHORT THE PROJECT GIVES NO CONNECTION ERROR OR EXECUTION ERROR BUT STILL VALUES ARE NOT INSERTED IN MY DATABASE (even it shows the success message `"successfully entered"`expected after successful execution as per my code)**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most importantly, your code is an extreme risk for SQL injection attacks.  Use parameters.

Comment: I am just testing..its not the final code I am just testing the feature i.e. using connection string via app.config. I will surely keep that in mind

Comment: Best practice is to not even test with insecure code, as it opens yourself up to missing things when you (hopefully eventually) refactor for production use.

Comment: Is Id a string?  You're enclosing it in single quotes as if it were, but the name sounds like it could be an identity int type value.

Comment: yes I am using it as string

Comment: Almost certainly, everything is working as it should and you are just looking in the wrong database or the right database at the wrong time.  Read [this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) to learn how local data files are managed.

Comment: No I am even trying to see the database when everything is closed but no data is found @jmcilhinney

Comment: Try to read the inserted row (or  total number of rows) using code. First just after insertion, second after closing and reopening the connection.

Comment: Do not open your connection in Form.Load and then wait for a button to be clicked to use it. Open it just before you use it. Also do not display message boxes before closing the connection. This applies even in test code.

Comment: "No I am even trying to see the database when everything is closed but no data is found". And which database are you looking at? Almost certainly the wrong one. You do realise that there are two databases, right? You do realise that, by default, the one you make changes to gets deleted every time you build, right? The fact that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns a value greater than zero is ABSOLUTE PROOF that data is being saved. If you can't see it, you're not looking properly. Trust me, I've seen this same issue HUNDREDS of times. Did you follow the link I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are indeed inserted in the database which is the local copy of the software installed on your machine and that data is exclusively available only for that instance of your installed application..So you might think where the data is going but data is inserted in the local instance of the database as jmcilhinney also said..And that datas are also only usable for that particular instance of application as it is a Local database.